# Google Meet Participant ID explanation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-meet

I am building a Chrome Extension for Google Meet, in which I need to uniquely identify all of the users (emails and such will not be good enough as a meeting can contain multiple participants of the same Google Account). I have noticed that in the source of the meeting HTML, each participant in the participants list is given a `data-participant-id` in the form of: `spaces/XXXXXXXXXXXX/devices/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`, where the first part is the same for every user, but seems to change from meeting to meeting, and the second part seems to be unique for every participant (doesn't matter for me whether it is unique within this meeting only or within all meetings).

My question is whether what I have assumed is correct or not, so is the first part actually unique for every meeting? And is the second part unique for every participant in the meeting?
Also, I would like to know who (outside of the meeting) has access to these IDs.

Comment: figure anything out here? With the most recent changes to Google meet, I'm not seeing a particular way to always grab the participant ID.  If the current user's video is in the bottom right (which it will be depending on the layout, number of users, and the "show in a tile" option), then I can't get it. Used to be you could just use "ssrc" but that doesn't show for tiled users now, and it's different than the participant ID.  I'm trying to force click the correct settings (tiled, tile shown) but I can't manage to get click actions to work either.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not achieve any further progress regarding this one :(